# Deleting all folders that aren't linked in a directory with bash

Tags: bash, directory, symlink

I have a task that requires me to delete all folders in a directory that aren't symlinked, keeping only the symlinked folders and the symlinks.

If I have for instance 3 resources: link, linked_folder and unlinked folder. link and linked_folder will be kept.

Currently I have managed to get this code, which works for the file naming structure we have, but I'd like to know if there is a cleaner solution?

```
protected_folders=`ls -l | awk '/^l/ {printf $10}' | tr '/' '|'`;
symlinks=`ls -l | awk '/^l/ {print $8}' | tr "\n" "|"`;
protected_resources=$protected_folders$symlinks;
protected_resources=${protected_resources:0:${#protected_resources}-1};
folders_to_delete=`ls | grep -v -E "$protected_resources"`; 
echo $folders_to_delete | tr '\n' ' ' | tr ' ' '\000' | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

I know the above command can be done on one line, but I've separated it as I've been requested to have it more "readable".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to move the symlinks and their targets to a new directory, then replace the old directory with the new.

WARNING: this is just a rough sketch, to give you the idea. [UPDATE: clean up and make it less like pseudo-code]

```
# Make an empty directory to hold the symlinks and targets
# that you want to keep
DIR_TO_CLEAN=/the/directory/to/clean/up
TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)

for x in $DIR_TO_CLEAN/*; do
    # Move each symlink and its target to the new directory
    [[ -h $x ]] && mv $x $(readlink -f $x) $TMP_DIR
done

# FIRST!!!, confirm that $TMP_DIR has everything you want to keep,
# and $DIR_TO_CLEAN has nothing you want to keep
rm -rf $DIR_TO_CLEAN
mv $TMP_DIR $DIR_TO_CLEAN
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is one possible solution, just run

```bsh
mkdir "./onlylinkedfiles" && cd "./onlylinkedfiles"
tar -ch "../symlinks" | tar -x --strip-components=1
```

and you got only and all files and dirs symlinked in `../symlinks/` within current directory.

#### Same with some automation:

```
cd "delete_here"
f="../symlinkshere"; mkdir ../temporary && pushd ../temporary && tar -vch "${f}" | tar -x --strip-components=1 && rm -rf "`dirs +1`" && cd .. && mv temporary "`dirs +1`" && popd
```

After that current directory contains only files that got symlinks at `../symlinkshere/`.

#### Let's break that down:

```bsh
# Specify directory where symlinks are:
f="../symlinkshere"; 
# Create temporary directory:
mkdir ../temporary && 
# Remember current and change cwd to temporary folder:
pushd ../temporary && 
# Copy all symlinked files and directories to cwd:
tar -vch "${f}" | tar -x --strip-components=1 && 
# Remove directory where we been when pushd called:
rm -rf "`dirs +1`" && 
# Cd out of temporary dir:
cd .. && 
# Rename temporary to original cwd
mv temporary "`dirs +1`" && 
# Go back to path where we started:
popd
```

### Here is shell script for easy use:

It works on current directory and takes one argument which is path to symlinks.
`cd /path/to/clean` 
`replacebylinks.sh /here/is/symlinks/`

**FILE:***`~/bin/replacebylinks.sh`*

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp="`mktemp -d`"
sourced="`readlink -f ${1}`"
workd="`pwd -P`"

cd "${tmp}"
tar -vchC "${sourced}" . | tar -xv --strip-components=1

rm -vrf "${workd}"
cd ..
mv -v "${tmp}" "${workd}" && cd "${workd}"
```

#### Some notes:

- Verbose switch `-v` can be removed from commands if you think that there is too much output.
- It may be better to use `tar -chC "source" .` as without `-C source` whole source directory tree is retained at destination. With absolute paths this starts from `/` root.

Comment: I don't see how this preserves the directories that have symbolic links pointing to them...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood.. So you want that normal dirs that have somewhere symlink pointing to them preserved and others, that do not have any symlinks pointing at them, removed?

Comment: @shellter: From my reading of Danger's description, I believe that both the directories linked to, and the symlinks live in the same directory... I don't think that we need to worry about links pointing out of the current directory structure.

Comment: @BartonChittenden : Sorry, you're not the O.P. I assumed you were. Doah! I'm deleting my comment above to reduce the chatter on this thread. sorry!

Comment: Yeah Barton is correct, I want to keep all folders that have symlinks pointing to them. To give you a better idea why, we have symlinks pointing to our current and previous release, and anything that is current or previous should be deleted on cleanup.

Comment: @Danger Got back behind kb and updated my answer as promised, only symlinked dirs or files preserved now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of the directories that you want to keep as follows:

```
keep_me=$(for link in $(find . -type l); do find -L . -samefile $link; done)
```

You could combine this with @chepner's solution like this:

```
mkdir ../new_tmp_dir
for link in $(find . -type l) 
do
    find -L . -samefile $link -print0
done | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} ../new_tmp_dir
rm -rf *
mv ../new_tmp_dir/* .
```

You may need to modify the find statements (using `-maxdepth=1`) if the directories that you're moving around are more than one level deep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'd call this cleaner, or elegant, or ridiculously complicated.  It's a lot of setup, but the last few lines of "real work" are clear enough.

```
# map - apply a function to all arguments
map() {
  fn="$1"
  shift
  for x in "$@"; do
    $fn $x
  done
}

echoif() { if $1 "$2" ; then echo $2 ; fi }

# use map/echoif to find items that meet a criteria in a list
filter() {
  op=$1
  shift
  map "echoif $op" "$@"
}

# list grep, essentially
find_in_list() {
  item=$1
  shift
  itemis() { test $item == $1 ; }
  res=`filter itemis "$@"`
  test -n "$res"
}

not() { if $* ; then return 1; fi ; }
not_in_list() { not find_in_list $* ; }

# utility functions for filtering
islink() { test -L $1 ; }
isdir() { test -d $1 ; }

# actual work starts here
links=`filter islink *`
dests=`map readlink $links`

should_delete() { not_in_list $1 $links $dests ; }

dirs=`filter isdir *`
todelete=`filter should_delete $dirs`

# you know what to do here    
echo rm -rf $todelete
```